# Saving files to another partition with PHP or Symbolic Link?

Tags: partition, php, webserver, hosting-services

We have a PHP based application running on a cPanel server which saves tons of API log files (millions), and we are looking to have the PHP scripts be able to write the API log text files into another partition (Amazon EFS mounted to server), so that we can more easily move those text files around.  The df-h output is below:

```
tmpfs           7.3G     0  7.3G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.3G  115M  7.2G   2% /run
tmpfs           7.3G     0  7.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      1.5T  623G  828G  43% /
/dev/loop0      3.9G  8.3M  3.7G   1% /tmp
127.0.0.1:/     8.0E  609G  8.0E   1% /smartefs01
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/1005
```

The drive that we want to save the files to is located in /smartefs01, the actual PHP application resides in /home/user/public_html .  We are struggling to find the easiest way to have the PHP application store files in /smartefs01 instead of /home/user_public_html.  Since we want to be able to detach the drive and move it around with all the files on it in cases of changing servers etc.

Let me know your thoughts!

Kind regards,

EC

Comment: that sounds like "how do I tell my PHP application where to write logs"; that should *really* be a functionality of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't symlink a file that does not yet exist, so that's not an option, if your application generates millions of files.

You could symlink or bind-mount a directory, if that application logs into a specific directory. Anyone will tell you that non-dangerous PHP server software should never write logs somewhere in `public_http`, anyways, for it not only risks inadvertedly exposing information to the public, but also basically nullifies any attempt of file-system-based suppression (SELinux) of an attacker managing to make log files contain things like `<?php…` tags and then making PHP load the log file as something to parse.

So, all in all, **your application** should be the one to be configured or modified to write its logs somewhere else. That's all: the most logical, the securest *and* the easiest way to solve this.